ML Kit Document Scanner | Google Play Service Crash
Have integrated ML Kit document scanner into the app currently I am working on.
In certain devices, the document scanner launches successfully but returns RESULT_CANCELLED under onActivityResult
On checking the logs, the Google play services is crashing with the below exception
GmsDocScanDelAct                         E  Failed to handle scanning result
                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to handle result
                                            atcom.google.mlkit.vision.documentscanner.internal.zzg.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-document-scanner@@16.0.0-beta1:12)
                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Currently use library version
dependencies {
    // …
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-document-scanner:16.0.0- 
    beta1'
}

Reference
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/doc-scanner/android
Seen in OnePlus / Samsung Android 9 devices
This is occuring in the document scanner present in Google Drive too


can you post your activity code ? Also post complete logcat as they have very important information about the crash.

We have the same error on Samsung Android 9 devices. In the beginning not all devices were affected, but now more and more users have the problem.
The causing error is probably the following:
com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 2127                                                                                               java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'm.bhv' does not implement interface 'android.view.PixelCopy$OnPixelCopyFinishedListener' in call to 'void android.view.PixelCopy$OnPixelCopyFinishedListener.onPixelCopyFinished(int)' 


Please also check bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/353441328
